# A top on a string from the perspective of forces

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, torque

You hang a rapidly spinning top on one end from a string and let it go.  It doesn't fall.  It rotates around the point where it is hung from the string.  Mathematically, I understand it.  Angular momentum is changed by torque, which is moment arm cross force.  So vertical gravity produces a horizontal change in angular momentum, etc.  I know the math and I can do it in my sleep!  I learned this years ago.  But still, after all this time, this system from the point of view of *forces* and *acceleration*, as opposed to angular momentum and torque, still makes no sense to me.  I still cannot "intuit" why the various *forces* involved somehow "conspire" to send the top in horizontal motion rather than pulling it down.  Anyone have an explanation?

Comment: Related [youtube video](https://youtu.be/XHGKIzCcVa0) by VSauce.

Comment: Relevant starting time in above video: 5:38